# problem with roboearth installation

Tags: roboearth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

can somebody help me in installing roboearth..im using ubuntu 11.04 ros electric...i follow provided  in ros wiki but cannot install....this is the output from the terminal

azfaryusof@azfaryusof-PC:~$ $ rosinstall ~/ros /opt/ros/electric 'http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=roboearth.rosinstall'
$: command not found
azfaryusof@azfaryusof-PC:~$ rosinstall ~/ros /opt/ros/electric 'http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=roboearth.rosinstall'
rosinstall operating on /home/azfaryusof/ros from specifications in rosinstall files  /opt/ros/electric, http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=roboearth.rosinstall
(Over-)Writing /home/azfaryusof/ros/.rosinstall
[pkgs/tum-ros-pkg/knowledge] Updating /home/azfaryusof/ros/pkgs/tum-ros-pkg/knowledge
[stacks/roboearth] Updating /home/azfaryusof/ros/stacks/roboearth
[stacks/ccny_vision] Updating /home/azfaryusof/ros/stacks/ccny_vision
WARNING [vcstools] Command failed: 'svn up  /home/azfaryusof/ros/stacks/roboearth'
errcode: 1 :
svn: Working copy '/home/azfaryusof/ros/stacks/roboearth' locked
svn: run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks (type 'svn help cleanup' for details)
[/vcstools]
[stacks/ccny_vision] Done.
[pkgs/tum-ros-pkg/knowledge] Done.
exception caught Error processing 'stacks/roboearth' : [stacks/roboearth] Update Failed of /home/azfaryusof/ros/stacks/roboearth

ERROR in config: Error processing 'stacks/roboearth' : [stacks/roboearth] Update Failed of /home/azfaryusof/ros/stacks/roboearth

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30021/problem-with-roboearth-installation/) by [ay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2017/ay/) on ROS Answers with karma: 9 on 2012-03-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2017/ay/) on 2012-04-16**:
as it said here....

for Ubuntu 10.10 systems with the ROS Electric binaries installed use

"rosinstall ~/ros /opt/ros/electric 'http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=roboearth.rosinstall'"

how about 11.04 system?

i think i missing something here...

**Comment by [ay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2017/ay/) on 2012-04-16**:
for ~/ros...do i need to change it to my own path?

**Comment by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) on 2012-04-16**:
It should work for Ubuntu 11.04 too. ~/ros is the directory where the stacks & packages will be downloaded to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try the hint given in the svn output (i.e. "locked svn: run 'svn cleanup' to remove locks"). Or you might try to just delete the whole directory and start from scratch again.

---

Originally posted by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) with karma: 916 on 2012-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1